# Steam OpenID dj-rest-auth dont return access token

Tags: python, django, dj-rest-auth

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from store.views import CaseViewSet, auth, GoogleLogin, VkLogin
from .settings import STEAM_CALLBACK_URL
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.steam.views import SteamOpenIDLoginView
import allauth


router = SimpleRouter()

router.register(r"case", CaseViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('auth/google/', GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login'),
    path("auth/vk", VkLogin.as_view(), name = "vk_login"),\
    path("auth/steam", SteamOpenIDLoginView.as_view(), name = "steam_login"),
    path('auth/steamcallback', allauth.socialaccount.providers.steam.views.SteamOpenIDCallbackView.as_view(), name = STEAM_CALLBACK_URL),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

in this code i create 2 endpoints.

I open page and login with steam openid and it return dont JWT .